# Mirroring A Large Production Database on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

As a hypothetical, let's say I own a company that runs SQL Server.  There is an enormous amount of data stored in a database (DB1) on the server, which is being queried both internally (for reporting purposes) and externally by my customers and causing a lot of slowness issues due to server traffic.  My question is, would it be a mistake or a good idea to mirror (exactly) DB1 and call it DB1b, so that my internal reporting could query DB1, and my customers could query DB1b?  Thanks.

Comment: there is at least half a dozen options to reduce the contention you are seeing... AlwaysOn AG, LogShipping, replication, DAGs, etc... this is far too broad and each come with their own pains and expenses, and you'd have to maintain them all. Please limit your question to something specific, aka [Minimal, Verifiable, and Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Hypothetically, your company would have an AlwaysOn configuration to prevent downtime and data loss that gets sync'd in realtime with basically no lag.

Hypothetically, your internal staff that is performing read-only operations could query against a secondary node in your availability group and your application/external customers who are doing read/write operations would connect to your primary node. If everyone is reading and no one is writing, you could stand up additional secondary nodes. Or just throw money at it and buy more processing power/RAM/cores.

Also, hypothetically, your queries could be garbage and they are not tuned. Once they are tuned with covering indexes, put into procs, etc, that would reduce waits/reads/etc.

Hypothetically, that would reduce the traffic. Overall, this post is way too broad to really answer without knowing more.

Comment: I'd also suggest log shipping in case they aren't running enterprise for AlwaysOn. It's far easier to manage, hypothetically. UV from me

Comment: @scsimon In this hypothetical, I'm assuming OP is making tons of cash as a business owner and can afford Enterprise licenses.

Comment: My apologies if the question is too broad, but I am not a dba.  I am an end user that is being told not to run queries because they are conflicting with the customer's ability to run their reporting.  I am not sure if the issue is network traffic, query optimization, or whatever else it could be.  i am just trying to brainstorm a solution that will make things better for everyone.

Comment: @mrfishel Sounds like this is an issue preventing you from doing your job. Punt it to your manager and say that you can't do your work or it will take a long time. Let him/her figure it out and you just do what you can with what you have. Brush up on query tuning, reading execution plans, and see if you can improve your code. If not, it is an infrastructure issue that is out of your control.

Comment: you start with what DF is suggesting by optimizing the queries (which seems like is NOT your job) falls to dba or developers. Then you add additional hardware functions like log shipping and finally, throw $ at it to put up more secondary servers. All 3 you have not control over but are stopping you from doing your work.